# Winsock in VB.net not working

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp, network-programming, winsock

Hey all i am trying to get this code that worked in VB6 just fine to work in VB.net 2008. It doesnt seem to want to connect (but has no error after it goes past the **sockMain.Connect()**.

```
sockMain.RemoteHost = "192.168.1.77"
sockMain.RemotePort = 77
sockMain.Connect()
```

Now when i do this:

```
On Error GoTo oops
    sockMain.SendData(txtSend.Text)

oops: 
    If Err.Number = 40006 Then
        MsgBox("It doesnt seem that the server is running. Please check it and try again")
    End If
```

I get the **It doesnt seem that the server is running. Please check it and try again.** error.

What am i missing??

David

Comment: The first thing you're missing is that VB 6 and VB.NET are *completely* different languages, with only some superficially similar syntax. Namely, `On Error GoTo` is *more* than deprecated in VB.NET, since structured exception handling (`try`/`catch`) is available to you now. Get a good book and learn not only the .NET idioms but also object-oriented programming in general. You'll be doing yourself a huge favor in the long run because the re-write you do from VB 6 to VB.NET will actually be worth doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I explained in a comment, VB.NET and VB 6 are almost entirely different programming languages. You're not doing yourself any favors by trying to write VB 6 code in VB.NET. There's no reason to migrate at all if you're not going to take advantage of the new features provided by the .NET platform.

Beyond the structured exception handling that I mentioned already, you should ditch the old WinSock control in favor of the classes found in the [`System.Net.Sockets` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.aspx).

Try replacing what you have with something like the following code:

```
Dim tcpClient As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
tcpClient.Connect("192.168.1.77", 77)
Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()
If networkStream.CanWrite And networkStream.CanRead Then
    ' Do a simple write.
    Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Is anybody there")
    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

    ' Read the NetworkStream into a byte buffer.
    Dim bytes(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
    networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))

    ' Output the data received from the host to the console.
    Dim returnData As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
    Console.WriteLine(("Host returned: " + returnData))
Else
    If Not networkStream.CanRead Then
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot not write data to this stream. " &
                          "Please check the server and try again.")
        tcpClient.Close()
    Else
        If Not networkStream.CanWrite Then
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot read data from this stream. " &
                              "Please check the server and try again.")
            tcpClient.Close()
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want the feeling of the vb6 winsock in .net world try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/winsock_revamped.aspx), beware it was not updated since 2008 and there is a few bug, look at the comment at the end of the acticle for more information

Answer (score 0):

The Connect call can take a little while to complete. Even if your client has made the physical connection to the server, you have to give it a wee while to establish the TCP virtual circuit. If you put a breakpoint on the call to SendData and wait just a second or two, then continue, you'll probably find that it works OK.